# jQuery get element offset from the top of the page

Tags: jquery, offset

I know there is offSet().top; and position().top;

but they both don't work in my case. I have to calculate the distance form the top of the window, of an element in position absolute. the problem with those methods is that they return the offset, not from the top of the page, but from the parent element that contains the absolute DIV. So I need to skip the parent container and get the real offset from the top of the page.

Some ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

I'm an idiot :-)

I mixed code up and wasn't updating what I was supposed to. I ended up using .offset().top; it does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>offset demo</title>
    <style>
        p {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>2nd Paragraph</p>

    <script>
        var p = $("p:last");
        var offset = p.offset();
        p.html("left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

From the [jQuery `.offset()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

> The `.offset()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) relative to the document. Contrast this with `.position()`, which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent. When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop), `.offset()` is more useful.